# TableView cells from different sections getting mixed up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to implement a tableview with two sections. Each section has one type of cell which will be needed.

So section one cells are subclassed as PendingTVC
section two cells are subclassed as ScheduledCell.

I have the follow methods implemented but the cells are getting mixed up. For example if section one has 3 cells, the first 3 cells in section 2 have a mixed up label which correlates to section one's first 3 cells. Code below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {


        if arr != nil {
            if section == 0 {
                print("returning pending : \(pendingCount)")
                return pendingCount
            }
            else{
                print("returning scheduled count : \(scheduledCount)")
                return scheduledCount
            }
        }
        return 0

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        if section == 0 {
            return "Pending"
        }
        else{
            return "Scheduled"
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let data = arr![indexPath.row]
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Pending") as? PendingTVC{
                PendingTVC.formattCell(cell: cell, data: data)
                cell.selectionStyle = .none;
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        }
        else{
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduledCell") as? ScheduledCell{
                print("cellforrowat in scheduledCell")
                ScheduledCell.formatCell(cell: cell, data: data)
                cell.selectionStyle = .none;
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Comment: Please attach a screenshot for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: you should return cell object ideally instead of UITableViewCell()

Comment: @air6199 this had no effect. I split up my data source into two arrays instead

Comment: if you could show me your arr i can help you through it without splitting into 2 arrays.

Comment: @user2363025 Yes i realised the issue, seems like i was beat to the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fetch your data inside your section condition. If you fetch data beforehand its ambiguous with indexpath data you require.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{       
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Pending") as? PendingTVC{
            let data = pendingarr![indexPath.row] //access pending data here
            PendingTVC.formattCell(cell: cell, data: data)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none;
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }
    }
    else{
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduledCell") as? ScheduledCell{
            print("cellforrowat in scheduledCell")
            let data = scheduledarr![indexPath.row] // access scheduled arr here
            ScheduledCell.formatCell(cell: cell, data: data)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none;
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't made any impact. You just increased one line in code.

Comment: pending and scheduled are both in the same array

Comment: @Surjeet I understand if there is sectional data , he must have array of dictionaries or array of array. he needs to access data according to section first .

Comment: As mentioned by @luckyShubhra, you need to have a different array for scheduled and pending, otherwise, you are just accessing the first n values of one section itself. Like if your section 0 has 3 elements you are accessing 1st three elements of array but, even for section 1, you are accessing the same first three elements.

Comment: let totalNumberOfRowsInFirstSection = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]

let data = arr![indexPath.section * totalNumberOfRowsInFirstSection + indexPath.row]

Comment: I changed the sections to use different arrays. It's now working. I thought I could just use the same array but obviously not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to use same array, you can get the data like I mentioned. @luckyShubhra

Comment: Glad you could resolve your issue. If my ans helped you kindly accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same data array for for both sections.

> let data = arr![indexPath.row]

Here you can see you are referencing indexPath.row as your index within your data array. This means the section is irrelevant. You have at least two options...

1. Create a 2d array in which the first index value is your section and the second is the row. e.g. dataArray = [[test, test2, test3], [otherTest, otherTest2, otherTest3]]. This can be accessed by changing your line to:

   > let data = arr![indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

or
2. Create two separate arrays... one for section 1 and one for section 2. Call them within your relevant checks for sections.